# how to get all tweets of a user using twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter

I'm a newbie in R and twitteR package. I am not able to scrape all tweets of a given user.

I tried following

```
user1<-"@IIMAhmedabad"
tweet_data1<-userTimeline(user = user1, n=3200)
```

the data contains not all tweets, only 888 tweet were retrieved?

How to download all tweets?

Comment: There is a limit on the number of tweets you can retrieve from a single call

Comment: @boski feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: the limit is 3200...but its not fetching as per limit

Comment: How old are the Tweets - there's a chance that some are too old to be retrieved.

Comment: it retrieved tweets upto 2016....total tweets are ranging from 2009 to 2018